# Folder Redirection Path is duplicated in Group Policy

Tags: group-policy, folder-redirection

Redirected Path for an applied group policy contains the path duplicated
e.g. if the path is supposed to be `\\FS01\share$\%USERNAME%\Desktop` the actual path applied is `\\FS01\share$\%USERNAME%\Desktop\\FS01\share$\%USERNAME%\Desktop`, as displayed from the output of `gpresult /v`

Roaming Profile path for the users is correct: `\\FS01\share$\%USERNAME%\profile` (which in Windows 10 1903 evals to ...\profile.V6)

We have tried to recreate the GPO, which results in the same issue. This configuration used to work: after fixing a replication issue between the two domain controllers, this issue started: not sure if this was the cause, but it was the only thing that changed.

### Edits

1. Removed unnecessary issue description.
2. Added TL;DR for quick reference
3. Added resources that led to resolution
4. Moved to answer below.

Comment: As this site is in a Q/A format, please post your solution as an answer instead of an edit of the question.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

### TL;DR

This is not an issue with Group Policy, but a quirk of the output of `gpresult /v`

### Description:

This is a output display issue. `gpresult /v` duplicates the path, but the actual path applied will be correct, which can be verified with `gpresult /h gpr.html` or `rsop`.

Please don't let the output fool you into thinking something is amiss when it isn't.

The final solution was found at [Changed Folder Redirection GPO, but setting will not take affect](https://social.technet.microsoft.com/Forums/windowsserver/en-US/25f2d9ba-881b-430c-bb72-03a124254dc3/changed-folder-redirection-gpo-but-setting-will-not-take-affect?forum=winserverGP), and was related to changes in server location not reflecting unless you remove the policy, and re-apply it again.

The output of `gpresult /v` will cause doubt on the validity of the changes, so I would recommend avoiding it an use `gpresult /h` or `rsop`